# Is Calling the `Wait()` method of `sync.Cond` Concurrently, Safe?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, locking, shared-state

Is calling the `Wait()` method of `sync.Cond` safe when according to the documentation, it performs an `Unlock()` first?

Assume we are checking for a condition to be met:

```
func sample() {
    cond = &sync.Cond{L: &sync.Mutex{}} // accessible by other parts of program

    go func() {
        cond.L.Lock()
        for !condition() {
            cond.Wait()
        }
        // do stuff ...
        cond.L.Unlock()
    }()

    go func() {
        cond.L.Lock()
        mutation()
        cond.L.Unlock()

        cond.Signal()
    }()
}
```

And:

```
func condition() bool {
    // assuming someSharedState is a more complex state than just a bool
    return someSharedState
}

func mutation() {
    // assuming someSharedState is a more complex state than just a bool
    // (A) state mutation on someSharedState
}
```

Since `Wait()` performs an `Unlock`, should (A) has a locking of it's own? Or being atomic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe to call `Wait` even when it calls `L.Unlock()` first but it is essential that you acquired the lock before calling `Wait` and before checking your condition since, in this situation, both are not thread safe.

> `Wait` atomically unlocks `c.L` **and suspends execution of the calling goroutine.** After later resuming execution, `Wait` locks `c.L` before returning.

1. The goroutine that calls `Wait` acquired the lock, checked the condition and found it to be unsatisfactory.
2. Now it waits but in order to allow for changes of the condition it needs to give the lock back. `Wait` does that automatically for you and then suspends the goroutine.
3. Now changes of the condition can happen and eventually the goroutine is awoken by `Broadcast` or `Signal`. It then acquires the lock to check the condition once again (This must happen one-by-one for each waiting goroutine or else there would be no way telling how many goroutines are running around freely now).

Comment: So `Unlock()` does not unlock the already locked `Cond` in another `goroutine`?

Comment: Silly me! I've already acquired the lock before calling `Wait()`!